# Why P-521 public key X,Y some time is 65 bytes some time is 66 bytes

Tags: security, go, elliptic-curve, ecdh

I use golang generate the P-521 public key.
source code look like that:

```
curve:=elliptic.P521()
priv, x, y, err := elliptic.GenerateKey(curve, rand.Reader)
xBytes:=x.Bytes()
yBytes:=y.bytes()
//len(xBytes)  some time is 65 bytes ,some time is 66 bytes
```

Why P-521 public key X,Y  not like P-256 or P-384 that have a fixed public key  length?

Comment: For the same reason that a random number from 1 and 1000 is some times 4 digits, some times, 3, sometimes 2, or sometimes 1 digit.

Comment: Why is this question marked as reproducible or caused by typos? Did someone think P-521 was a typo? I think this question is valid and clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`secp521r1` uses a 521-bit prime field.  So the X or Y coordinates are represented as 521-bit numbers.  Yes, 521, not 512.

521 bits is 65 full bytes and one bit left over.  In a fixed-size encoding of the public key the most significant byte would always have the 7 most significant bits set to 0, and the 8th bit will be 1 or 0 (so the whole byte is 0x00 or 0x01).

Since the coordinate space isn't *quite* all of the 521-bit numbers, you have a slightly less than 50% chance of the high bit being set for any particular point.

Go's method seems to be returning the value using a minimum-byte representation.  So you should see something like

- 66 bytes: 49% of the time
- 65 bytes: 50% of the time
- 64 bytes (top 9 bits are all 0): 0.2%
- (63 bytes and below are possible, but with vanishingly small percentages)

Comment: In case of applications that requires fixed length representation (such as JWK), what is the "best way" to adjust length if the returned key is not 66 bytes long ? Will it work as intended if I just fill the missing cells with a null sequence ? ("\x00")

Comment: @KawaLo So long as it's not inside any sort of length-prepended structure, sure, you could add prefix zeroes.  (e.g. you couldn't do it inside a certificate's SubjectPublicKeyInfo since it has length values, you'd need to recompute everything... then re-sign the cert.)

Comment: do yo happen to know the RFC document explaining this binary format in details? it would greatly help me!.

Comment: @m.eldehairy It's just a big-endian representation of an integer with all leading zeros omitted.  There's not really a spec to consult (to my knowledge).

Comment: @bartonjs, thanks for your reply. I meant for the whole key coordinates + private key including the prefix byte X, Y and optionally the private key

Comment: @m.eldehairy probably https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf, then. That’s all the “how do you write down ECC” stuff