# ECDH for P-521 (Web Crypto Api) / secp521r1 (NodeJS Crypto) generate a slightly different shared secret

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, webcrypto-api, ecdh

I have generated a public and private key pair with `ECDH` from NodeJS

```
function _genPrivateKey(curveName = "secp384r1", encoding = "hex") {
    const private_0 = crypto.createECDH(curveName);
    private_0.generateKeys();
    return private_0.getPrivateKey().toString(encoding);
}
```

**BOB PRIVATE KEY**

```
9d0c809d692c83c7d8d1355205dd78e679066fd9c15d12cdea3e1103b041873765264351e8939083b876d89d423301d8486a956da455ddbdc4a91ef60af7dd2325
```

**BOB PUBLIC KEY**

```
[hex] 
0400d7a342e89f501e1cd8224e2463ef1ad057c9b64bf45c1d3627cc1f06c055c80f75c2013c27b63dc984b467ecfc5202cf9a126ef1f1487e92b9acfb52abaeb7022e01f4259918ca34f442214a31d1bad329f9be1c67ce98af6621f622e44887264e856ee8c664a51e56f24008c932ee1cb5514c02d03ba27f6b6a1cd0aa0f8eac261250

[jwk] {
  key_ops: [ 'deriveKey' ],
  ext: true,
  kty: 'EC',
  x:'ANejQuifUB4c2CJOJGPvGtBXybZL9FwdNifMHwbAVcgPdcIBPCe2PcmEtGfs_FICz5oSbvHxSH6Suaz7UquutwIu',
  y:'AfQlmRjKNPRCIUox0brTKfm-HGfOmK9mIfYi5EiHJk6FbujGZKUeVvJACMky7hy1UUwC0Duif2tqHNCqD46sJhJQ',
  crv: 'P-521'
}
```

and `Alice`'s keys from a web page with **Web Crypto API**

```
const generateAlicesKeyPair = window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
        name: "ECDH",
        namedCurve: "P-521"
    },
    false,
    ["deriveBits"]
);
```

**ALICE PUBLIC KEY**

```
04000eefa90c3de22e79e6742f807806a603059d16afaa9f1bc69f420050aae100d0006e6510fe17a8f6767fe1e69bada039175ef5a375e30af4085e4315cf7527655f00ed9a39552a5f9170cc7626c1f4584d0e6de17870e336bcc5b6e251e3ea2c7cd9633e1afe2f9aee5f9a7445d38218c20695cc7ba2a462b67ce39a060e6464133609
```

---

When I try to derive the `shared key` a strange thing happens, the key has different bits at the end.

**NodeJS:**

```
function _getSharedSecret(privateKey, publicKey, curveName = "secp521r1", encoding = "hex") {
    const private_0 = crypto.createECDH(curveName);
    private_0.setPrivateKey(privateKey, encoding);
    const _sharedSecret = private_0.computeSecret(publicKey, encoding);
    return _sharedSecret
};
```

**Web Crypto API**

```
const sharedSecret = await window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits({
        name: "ECDH",
        namedCurve: "P-521",
        public: publicKey
    },
    privateKey, 
    521
);
```

> Results:

```
//NodeJS: 
0089b99212c9348a6fd3aa78225a773a90ef45f57bbd10dc86d8e52fa26662c550b56d2368ee358ab240ceec10191b6cdd7d09bb0a8763ea48a487a5676ebdf7af[eb]

//WebCryptoAPI:

0089b99212c9348a6fd3aa78225a773a90ef45f57bbd10dc86d8e52fa26662c550b56d2368ee358ab240ceec10191b6cdd7d09bb0a8763ea48a487a5676ebdf7af[80]
```

This happens only with the curve **P-521/secp521r1** but not with the curves **P-256/secp256r1** and **P-384/secp384r1**

Comment: Could you test the result by selecting the same private key and printing the points for each side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking with a third library (Python, *Cryptography* library) shows that the NodeJS result is the correct one (i.e. the one ending with `0xEB`).

X and Y coordinates of P-521 are represented by 66 bytes (521 bit = 65 bytes + 1 bit) (s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50007190)). The shared secret is the X coordinate of a curve point (s. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman#Key_establishment_protocol)) and therefore also has 66 bytes = 528 bits. This value is to be specified in the *WebCrypto API* implementation in `deriveBits()` as the length of the shared secret.

If you specify 521 bits only the highest bit (which is set for `0xEB`) is taken into account, the remaining bits are set to `0`, resulting in the value `0x80`.

The following code illustrates this (please note that the script doesn't run under Firefox, which is presumably a bug):

```js
(async () => {
    await getSharedSecret(521);
    await getSharedSecret(528);
})();

async function getSharedSecret(bits) {
    var bobPrivateKeyJwk = {   
        kty: "EC",
        crv: "P-521",
        x:'ANejQuifUB4c2CJOJGPvGtBXybZL9FwdNifMHwbAVcgPdcIBPCe2PcmEtGfs_FICz5oSbvHxSH6Suaz7UquutwIu',
        y:'AfQlmRjKNPRCIUox0brTKfm-HGfOmK9mIfYi5EiHJk6FbujGZKUeVvJACMky7hy1UUwC0Duif2tqHNCqD46sJhJQ',
        d: "AJ0MgJ1pLIPH2NE1UgXdeOZ5Bm_ZwV0Szeo-EQOwQYc3ZSZDUeiTkIO4dtidQjMB2EhqlW2kVd29xKke9gr33SMl",
        ext: true,
    }
    var alicePublicKeyBuffer = typedArray('04000eefa90c3de22e79e6742f807806a603059d16afaa9f1bc69f420050aae100d0006e6510fe17a8f6767fe1e69bada039175ef5a375e30af4085e4315cf7527655f00ed9a39552a5f9170cc7626c1f4584d0e6de17870e336bcc5b6e251e3ea2c7cd9633e1afe2f9aee5f9a7445d38218c20695cc7ba2a462b67ce39a060e6464133609');    
    var privateKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "jwk", 
        bobPrivateKeyJwk,
        { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-521" },
        true, 
        ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"] 
    );
    var publicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw", 
        alicePublicKeyBuffer.buffer,
        { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-521"},
        true, 
        [] 
    );
    var sharedSecret = await window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits(
        { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-521", public: publicKey },
        privateKey, 
        bits 
    );
    console.log("Bob's shared secret:\n", buf2hex(sharedSecret).replace(/(.{48})/g,'$1\n'));
}; 

function typedArray(hex) {
    return new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) { // from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43131635
        return parseInt(h, 16)
    }))
}

function buf2hex(buffer) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join(''); // from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031979/9014097 
}
```

With the curves P-256 and P-384 the problem does not occur, because the prime field is already a multiple of 8 (32 bytes and 48 bytes, respectively).